# live stream desktop to android tablet and delay

Tags: android, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, live-streaming

I am trying to live stream the desktop to android tablet. Here is what I did

1) Capture the screen using the ffmpeg

`ffmpeg -y -f x11grab -s 800x600 -r 20 -i :0 http://x.x.x.x:8090/feed1.ffm`

2) Stream using ffserver

Here is  partial ffserver.conf file

```
<Stream test>
Feed feed1.ffm
Format flv
NoAudio                                                
VideoSize 800x600                                      
</Stream>
```

3) Play the stream on the tablet (Android 4.3) using URL "http://x.x.x.x:8090/test"

I am able to see the desktop on tablet with few issues
1) There is around 6 to 8 secs delay in the video
2) player shows a warning "first frame is no keyframe"

When I changed the "Format flv" to "Format mpegts" in "ffserver.conf" file the warning is gone. But the delay is still there.

Is there a way to reduce the delay?

Am I using the correct format?

I want to achieve at max 2 sec delay for my desktop streaming.

Answer (score 0):

What are you using at the android device to view the video? The question looks quite generic.

1. Are you just sending raw frames to the receiver? In that case, they might be quite a bit heavy and it take some time to process them. See if you can actually encode them and stream to network.
2. Secondly, It also depends in network latency, how good is your network?  Give a try in a WLAN first and then try it between two public IP Numbers.
3. What is the size of your jitter-buffer at the receiver? If you have large jitter-buffer, players set some percentage limit to fill before it can actually kick playing. Apparently if you have large jitter-buffer it might take long time to fill it and so initial delay for your video. So, in test cases shutdown the jitter-buffer.
4. I could also blame the decoding capabilities of your receiver device.

Comment: I am using Vitamio SDK (http://www.vitamio.org/en/) to play the video stream on Nexus 10, Android 4.3

Comment: 1) Video stream is being sent in flv format, not raw. 2) I have good wireless connectivity 20Mbps 3) I am using the media player provided by Vitamio SDK. Which has 1024KB buffer size as default. I also tried changing this value (0 to 1MB), but no change in the delay.

Comment: oh. okay! 'flv' i remember as a container format. But anyways, even i don't know beyond that. Lets wait until someone else responds.

Comment: if you are using linux system, then use VLC player source code which is open to use. Their is no delay in that. stream is too good with vlc player.